# ImportError: No module named requests.exceptions

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

This is a strange error which works well with other environment but with my ubuntu18 + python 2.7, it throws below error:

```
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/user/p4/stage-1/web-ui/machines/models.py", line 20, in <module>
    from requests.exceptions import (
ImportError: No module named requests.exceptions
```

I am trying to use exceptions from requests:

```
from requests.exceptions import (
    HTTPError,
    RetryError
)
```

I tried updating requests to v2.7.0 (pip install requests)
removed python-requests (sudo apt remove python-requests)
but still same error. Any pointer please?

Comment: Do you have a file named `requests` in same directory?

Comment: Its a module...

Answer (score 1):

If i remember correctly, you can import the exception types directly from the root module, so try removing `.exceptions` from your import.

Comment: Only for some of `requests` exceptions. E.g. The `ProxyError` class has to be imported from `requests.exceptions`